# Finding linear map to show $\dim_k V/W = n$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $V = k[x]$ and $W \subseteq V$ be the subspace of polynomials divisible by some polynomial of degree $n$. Then it is a known fact that $\dim_k V/W = n$, and this is often shown by looking at the images of $1, x, \ldots, x^{n-1}$ in $V/W$ and proving that they form a basis.

I want to know if it is possible to instead show this fact by finding a surjective linear map $T: V \to k^n$ such that $\ker (L) = W$? By the isomorphism theorem we would then be done.

I have tried things such as evaluating a polynomial (and its derivatives) at its roots but this does not work in for example $\mathbb{R}$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let $g$ be your polynomial. There is a surjective linear map $T: V \to P_n$, where $P_n$ is the space of polynomials of degree less than $n$, given by taking any polynomial $f$, using polynomial division to write $f = gq_f + r_f$ with $r \in P_n$ and setting $T(f) = r_f$. This is essentially the same proof as the one you're trying to avoid, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map that assigns to each polynomial its remainder when you divide by a polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ is surjective onto the vector space of polynomials of degree less then $n$. If you agree that space has dimension $n$ then you are done, since the kernel is just the polynomials divisible by $p$.

As @IzaakvanDongen comments, agreeing to that dimension count is not far from the proof you want to avoid.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Yes, Fixed thanks. (You could have edited.)